# Empty string with multiple blank problem in JSF - SPRING - HIBERNATE

Tags: string, hibernate, spring, jsf

i have a simple problme.
I need to catch when a user enter an empty string in a form and display the appropriate error message.
I'm trying with jsf required attribute, but if the user enter "   " a string like that the validation go next without error.
I had try Spring annotation @NotNull and Hibernate @NotEmpty, but nothing solve the problem.
Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about the Spring part, but in Hibernate you can use [`@NotBlank`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.1/api/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/NotBlank.html) annotation for this:

```
@NotBlank
private String value;
```

Or, you could create a JSF converter for `String.class` which does the job:

```
package com.example;

import javax.faces.component.EditableValueHolder;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter;

@FacesConverter(forClass=String.class)
public class EmptyToNullConverter implements Converter {

    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, String value) {
        if (value == null || value.trim().isEmpty()) {
            if (component instanceof EditableValueHolder) {
                ((EditableValueHolder) component).setSubmittedValue(null);
            }
            return null;
        }
        return value;
    }

    public String getAsString(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        return (value == null) ? null : value.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: Ok, the last solution work well.
For the @NotBlank i'm unable to work it, because the only annotation that i must use is @NotEmpty.
Maybe because i'm using Hibernate 3.2.5?

Comment: You're welcome. It's indeed introduced in later Hibernate versions.

Comment: Ok, while if i want using Spring annotation there isn't a solution?
However for ur last solution if i already usa a converter i need to merge the  code? or there is a solution that able me to use 2 converter?